# Eclipse: Web services: 404 error using Tomcat7

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7

I'm using this link to create a web service using the buttom-up approach: http://dtechtalkcenter.blogspot.com/2012/10/creating-code-first-web-service-bottom.html .

However, I'm getting this error no matter what I do :

> Etat HTTP 404 - /StandardWebService/services/ProductServiceImplPort
>
> type Rapport d''état
>
> message /StandardWebService/services/ProductServiceImplPort
>
> description La ressource demandée n''est pas disponible.

Your help would be appreciated ;)

Comment: Include the code of the classes that you use, please. Reading the manual I wonder if you have used the same package defined in the examples. If you don't change this line @WebService(endpointInterface ="com.dtechtalkcenter.service.ProductService") using your own package, it could lead to the error that you are getting.

Comment: I have named the package: testeurfinal1 and I have written in the ProductServiceImpl : @WebService(endpointInterface ="testeurfinal1.ProductService"). In the error report, I'm having this remark: AVERTISSEMENT: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:testeurfinal1' did not find a matching property.

Comment: But it's just a warning. When it comes to 404 error, web.xml is generally thought to be having some problem (extra annotations) but I couldn't figure out what's wrong with it...

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce the manual steps. It may take a while.

Comment: Sorry, I can not deploy the webservice either. The xsd files generated got conflicts with the namespaces. When I try to start the server, service definition is not found. Look in your console to get the stack trace that is provoking to abort creation and ask again. :-(

Comment: Thank you for trying to solve this problem... I didn't get your last point: How can I get the stack trace that is provoking to abort creation using the console?

Comment: I mean Eclipse console. When you start the Tomcat server (in the last step of creating the WebService you do it inadvertently), its traces appears in the "console" tab writed in red. Probably at some point of this traces, you're getting the error. Something in the line of "can not initialize bean: blablablahexception"

Answer (score 0):

Ey! I have deployed the WebService finally!!

The only change I've made in the classes provided by your link is adding targetNamespace in class ProductService.

```
  package es.rubioric.ws;

  import java.util.List;

  import javax.jws.WebParam;
  import javax.jws.WebService;

  @WebService(targetNamespace="http://ws.rubioric.es/")
  public interface ProductService {
       //Return List of product
       List<Product> getProducts();

       //add the product into the list
       void addProduct(@WebParam(name="product")Product product);
   }
```

EDT: Include Service Impl

```
  package es.rubioric.ws;

  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;
  import javax.jws.WebService;

  @WebService(endpointInterface ="es.rubioric.ws.ProductService")
  public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService{

  @Override
  public List<Product> getProducts() {

       List<Product> product=new ArrayList<Product>();
       product.add(new Product("Windows","OS", "windows server", 300));
       product.add(new Product("Linux","OS", "Linux server", 100));
       product.add(new Product("Mac","OS", "Mac server", 500));
       return product;
  }

  @Override
  public void addProduct(Product product) {
        System.out.println(product);
  }
}
```

It's seems very important the last slash ('/') in the targetNamespace included in this class. I don't know how works the automatic generation mechanism used but it generates two namespaces: http://ws.rubioric.es/ and http://ws.rubioric.es

Including the slash, these namespaces are **different** - which seems a good thing [sorry for my poor explanation, I don't know much about this kind of WebServices] and allow deployment.

[image: Running at last!]

I include this other image for explaining you what I mean with console

[image: Eclipse console]

It's always red, don't mind the color, but there is where you're going to get a stacktrace pointing the problem.

Another tip: In Eclipse Mars, after this window

[image]

if your push next twice, appears a SOAP configuration window.

[image: SOAP]

Uncheck the "Generate separate XSD ..." to avoid extra conflicting xsd file generation.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you for responding but I'm still getting the same error. Actually, I have a question: You have written : "http://ws.rubioric.es/" as a targetnamespace and you have named the package: es.rubioric.ws. My package is called 'testeurfinal1'. So, the targetnamespace is "http://testeurfinal1/',isn't?...

Comment: The second question is about the fifth step in the link: http://dtechtalkcenter.blogspot.com/2012/10/creating-code-first-web-service-bottom.html : In the service implementation field, have you written: com.dtechtalkcenter...? That didn't work for me. So, I have chose chosen : testeurfinal1.ProductServiceImpl for that field... I'm trying to get to know what didn't go well... :/

Comment: @JohnPacker I have included my service implementation above. Namespace must be an URL. Your targetnamespace do not seems correct. Try changing your package including in it your country (or your best ever country) and modifying the namespace accordingly

Comment: I recreated the whole project. The WSDL and XSD files and generated but I'm still having the 404 error. This is what I'm getting: http://imgur.com/edit and this one is speaking about the exception that occured: http://imgur.com/Zxpz5Kz

Comment: I can not access the first image. In relation to the second one, seems a problem with the web service generating library. I've used Apache-cfx 3.1.5.

Comment: @JohnPacker Also no need for images linked, you can edit your original question and paste the stacktrace above. Useful for me and for anybody that may not read this comments ;-)

Comment: @JohnPacker I think that I have earned at least a +1 in my answer :-)